# PHP - suppress PDO errors and warnings

Tags: php, error-handling

Is possible to suppress PDO error in php using the `@`? I know it's a bad practice, I'm asking this to understand better how the `@` error suppression operator works in php

Comment: _" I know it's a bad practice"_ - absolutely. I've never used the @ operator, and I can't understand why it even exists!

Comment: You can always do `try{} catch(\Exception $e){}` and handle the errors in more meaningful way (or discarge it if you will). Btw, supressing the errors is ALWAYS a bad idea for system operator and your application clients, especially if it include permanent data, where probably some kind of sensitive data is stored.